# Unmarshalling XML response with namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, unmarshalling

I'm using JAXB to marshall and unmarshall requests and responses to a web service I'm implementing a Java client for. I am however stuck on the following response that I need to unmarshall.

```xml
<ResultCollection xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <FailedItems xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        <a:KeyValueOflongstring>
            <a:Key>12345</a:Key>
            <a:Value>Some clever message here</a:Value>
        </a:KeyValueOflongstring>
    </FailedItems>
    <SucceededItems xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
</ResultCollection>
```

To represent the response as Java objects, I have the following domain classes:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name="ResultCollection")
public class ResultCollectionResponse
{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="FailedItems", namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    @XmlElement(name = "KeyValueOflongstring")
    public List<KeyValueOflongstring> FailedItems = new ArrayList<KeyValueOflongstring>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="SucceededItems", namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    @XmlElement(name = "long")
    public List<Long> SucceededItems = new ArrayList<Long>();
}

public class KeyValueOflongstring
{
    public Long Key;
    public String Value;
}
```

I'm then doing the following to unmarshal:

```java
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(ResultCollectionResponse.class);
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

// inputStream holds the XML content from the web service
ResultCollectionResponse response = (ResultCollectionResponse)u.unmarshal(inputStream);
```

The unmarshalling happens without incident. The `ResultCollectionResponse` object is created with two lists. `SucceededItems` is empty and `FailedItems` has one item. However, `Key` and `Value` on that item is null. I'm thinking this has to do with XML namespaces, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it.

I tried going the other way so to speak by creating dummy objects in Java code and marshalling them into XML. When I do that, I end up with the following XML:

```xml
<ResultCollection xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <FailedItems>
        <ns2:KeyValueOflongstring>
            <Key>12345678</Key>
            <Value>Some clever message here</Value>
        </ns2:KeyValueOflongstring>
    </FailedItems>
    <SucceededItems/>
</ResultCollection>
```

As you can see, the namespace has been applied to the top level element rather than the `FailedItems` and `SucceededItems` elements. I don't understand why that is. Also, as you can see, I don't have the http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance namespace on the top level element because if I do, the unmarshalling fails with the exception `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"ResultCollection"). Expected elements are <{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}ResultCollection>`. This error message confuses me even further because the response XML clearly has said namespace.

I don't usually work with Java and XML namespaces is something that I have always kind of tried to ignore. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following.  In your example it is the elements with the prefix that are namespace qualfied, not the elements that contain the namespace declaration.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ResultCollection")
public class ResultCollectionResponse
{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="FailedItems")
    @XmlElement(name = "KeyValueOflongstring", namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    public List<KeyValueOflongstring> FailedItems = new ArrayList<KeyValueOflongstring>();

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="SucceededItems")
    @XmlElement(name = "long")
    public List<Long> SucceededItems = new ArrayList<Long>();
}
```

```java
public class KeyValueOflongstring
{
    @XmlElement(namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    public Long Key;

    @XmlElement(namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")
    public String Value;
}
```

Comment: Hallelujah! I could swear I had tried that variant as well, but apparently not. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you could use the xjc tool to generate the Java classes from the XML schema automatically. It is a better guarantee that they will work with the XML schema than if you create the classes manually. Xjc is part of the JDK.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will look into the xjc tool. However, my immediate problem was solved by the answer by Blaise.